# Error during mscore font installation

Tags: 15.10

I got through the installation agreement, but this error won't go away. I have completely uninstalled the program, but every time i re-install it, i get this error.

[image]

Comment: That's generally a sign of a bad connection. Can you move close to the WiFi access point or plug directly into it?

Comment: Please don't use images for code. Copy/paste it into the question

Comment: to be honest, im paying the best wifi connection, runs at 64mbps. but i hav e tried that also, plugging in the ethernet  cable and i still get the same error. yah sorry about the pictures, im new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783). I couldn't Find a proper solution but i did find a work around.

**Deleting partially downloaded**

1. Open terminal <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>
2. `cd /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial`
3. `sudo rm *`
   If this dosent work you can try the workaround

**skiping  hash sum check**
This is not a solution but a workaround this is not recommened as it skips the hash sum check.

```
 TMP=`mktemp -d`
cd $TMP
grep Url: /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 wget
sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts $TMP/*
cd -
rm -rf $TMP
```

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783)

Comment: it did delete the partial. now i think i should reinstall, the program. thx so much

Comment: No problem Just let me know if my solution worked after trying it

Comment: yesss. i reinstalled it through the software center by typing mscore, and rebooted. it worked, finally now i can finish my High School Honors Literature Project. Thanks Mohit and thx for everyone who tried to help in the comment section.